# How to bypass this regex error when downloading udemy videos

Tags: python, linux, download

I am trying to download the entire course of videos from udemy.

After following the instructions and getting the necessary packages installed, I get the error below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/udemy-dl", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 837, in main
    udemy_dl(username, password, link, lecture_start, lecture_end, save_links, safe_file_names, just_list, output_dest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 658, in udemy_dl
    login(username, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 109, in login
    csrf_token = get_csrf_token()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 102, in get_csrf_token
    return match.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I am using linux 18.04 and I have installed python 2.7 already. I can be successfully authenticated to udemy from the command line but I am not able to get the videos. Does anyone know how can I get solve this regex error?

Comment: That's not problem with pip, that's problem with regex inside this package - there's no match found, hence the object is `None`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of struggling with this python module, you can use this package

https://github.com/maabiddevra/udemy-dl/

No need to deal with python and no need to install just get the executable files from library bin folder and you are ready to go.

Comment: It seems like a relatively new package. I will give it a try soon . Thanks